# Multiple insert queries

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb3

I have three tables that essentially cascade down, like:

- topic
- section (references topic id)
- subsection (references topic id and section id)

Whats the best method of writing mysql statements to create the initial topic/section/subsection so I can grab the id's (auto_incremented) of the newly created rows and use them to insert them into the second two?

*edit* 
I'm using phpbb3, dunno if that makes a huge difference, but I normally use the $db-sql_query() function

Comment: `$db->sql_query($sql) ; $db->insert_id;` if your `if ($db instanceof mysqli)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the parent, down the line.
Then you can use either [LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html), or INSERT in the SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO TOPIC
  (topic_id, topic)
VALUES (DEFAULT, $topic);

INSERT INTO SECTION
  (topic_id, section)
SELECT topic_id, $section
  FROM TOPIC
 WHERE topic = $topic

INSERT INTO SUBSECTION
  (section_id, topic_id, subsection)
SELECT section_id, topic_id
  FROM SECTION 
 WHERE section = $section
```

This example assumes that `TOPIC.topic_id`, `SECTION.section_id`, and `SUBSECTION` are auto_increment, primary key columns.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mysql_insert_id() to get the last insert ID. see [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, there's only one way, which is top-down.
To add a subsection to a section, you must have had a section already inserted.
To add a topic to a subsection, make sure you added the subsection first.
On the way, you keep track of the last inserted ID (if you just created it) to give it to the next entity down the line.

Comment: I get conceptually how to do it, I'm trying to figure out how to grab and save each id from an auto_increment and pass it along to the next query.. I suppose I should update the question with that

Comment: Manny got that specific answer.